# Minecraft command skips enchantment

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command that doesn't work for some reason.

`/summon Item ~ ~1.2 ~ {CustomName:"Hidden Blade",CustomNameVisible:1,Item:{id:wooden_sword,Count:1,ench:[{id:13,lvl:3}]}`

Comment: This command looks completely normal. Please tell us what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket, but the game already tells you exactly that, so I don't know how you didn't see it.

Comment: The NBT is incorrect, which you can check in the wiki. Also I have no idea what enchantment ID 13 is supposed to be, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your enchantment id 13 is working here is the working command:

```
/summon Item ~ ~1.2 ~ {Item:{id:wooden_sword,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Hidden Blade"},ench:[{id:13,lvl:3}]}}}
```